# Насколько важно MVC в PHP

Tags: php, yii2, ооп, mvc

Я тут застрял в MVC и надолго, терпение немножко не хватает. Прошелся по очень Важным вещам, то есть, как пишется модель, контроллер и т.д.. Но как сяду писать простенький интернет-магазин, то сразу теряюсь, что писать, где писать и так уже 2 месяца. Понимание есть, но по реализациям 0.
Если есть хорошие ресурсы, которых я не заметил, то дайте пожалуйста!

И получится ли, если приступлю к фрейморку, например YII2, понять, что где находится. Реально немножко срываюсь(

Comment: MVC бывает разных видов, поскольку само понимание модели и контроллера несколько отличается в некоторых фреймворках. Ты сейчас говоришь про бизнес-логику, когда говоришь, куда что писать. В некоторых случаях бизнес-логика выносится в отдельные сервисы, а не пишется в моделях. Понимаю, что слегка некорректно это тут писать, но мне как раз очень нужен человек, которого буду подтягивать по знаниям взамен на различную помощь в легких проектах (оплата само собой). Если хочешь - напиши мне в тг @alexxosipov :) Про MVC еще сейчас несколько ссылок скину

Comment: читайте документацию к фреймворку, там все с примера будет, как разрабатывать приложение. Если вы хотите без особого опыта взять и написать свою реализацию mvc и построить на этом инет-магазин, то не стоит. возьмите готовые фреймворки и работайте с ними.

Answer (score 1):

В основном, MVC бывает 2 видов:

- Толстый контроллер, тонкая модель
- Тонкий контроллер, толстая модель

Очень много споров, что есть правильно, а что нет. Итог этих споров - несколько стандартов разработки по паттерну MVC. Полагаю, что ты уже прочел [это](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-View-Controller#%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C) и знаешь основы MVC, хоть и без практики. Если перейти к проекту с интернет-магазином, то у нас есть следующие модели:

- Товар
- Категория
- Заказ
- Клиент

Для наглядности, берем за основу самый базовый интернет-магазин с одним уровнем вложенности. Модель является "поставщиком" данных для контроллеров, она никак не связана с пользователями и её задача лишь управлять данными. У каждой модели есть связи (категория имеет много товаров, товар имеет одну категорию, заказ имеет несколько товаров и одного клиента, клиент имеет много заказов, товар может принадлежать нескольким заказам), наша цель - написать все эти связи в модель. К примеру, возьмем модель заказа (пишу так, как пишется на laravel, но для yii примерно так же делается):

```
class Order extends Model
{
  //Получаем клиента
  public function client()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Client');
  }

  //Получаем товары
  public function client()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Products');
  }
}
```

Зачем это надо? Для того, чтобы придерживаться принципа DRY и не утолщать контроллер. Теперь представим метод контроллера, который обрабатывает запрос на получение заказа по ID:

```
...controller
public function show($orderId)
{ 
  $order = Order::findOrFail($orderId);     
  return view('view.name', $order);
}
```

Таким образом, хелпер `view()` рендерит пользователю view, при этом передавая туда переменную `$order`.

Различные вопросы защиты данных и т.д. выходят из рамок MVC и реализуются в каждом фреймворке по-разному.

Надеюсь, что это хоть немного тебе помогло :)

Comment: думаю, поможет через несколько дней, а лучше ли начинать учить фреймворк и вместе рассматривать MVC? Там каркас такой же вроде)

Answer (score 0):

Да, если начнёте изучать MVC вместе с фреймворком - точно не прогадаете. Я бы вам посоветовал обратить внимание на фреймворки Laravel, либо Symfony. Yii2 - хороший инструмент, но он во-первых на данный момент развивается значительно слабее первых двух, во вторых он в некоторых случаях прививает плохие практики разработки.